# Spherical wave amplitude near to source

Tags: waves, energy-conservation

Let us assume, I generate spherical waves from a point source, of the form $f(t)=\sin(t)$. At $r$ distance, it will be $\sin(t)/r$. Let us take $r = 0.1$ for example. Then, at this distance, the amplitude will be $10 \sin(t)$. Doesn't that conflict the conservation of energy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it is worth, your formulation of the spherical wave business is flawed. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation#Spherical_waves) for example. These have the form $$u(r, t) = \frac{A}{r} e^{i(\omega t \pm k r)},$$ where the symbols have their usual meaning. So, intensity, which goes as the amplitude squared, will go as $$I = \left(\frac{A}{r}\right)^2$$ falling off as the square of the distance, which is fine.

Anyways, the source of the trouble in your formulation is not just that the spherical waves are mis-represented, but actually that your "increasing with $r$" argument is flawed. You took $r = 0.1$ in your amplitude form $\sin t /r$, but took for granted that at the source point itself, the number is $\sin t$ only, and starts falling off as $\sin t /r$ only beyond  $r=0$. Thus, even within this flawed formulation, intensity is falling off with $r$ contrary to your belief, as $I_{r=0} \rightarrow \infty$, which has fallen down to a finite number $10 \sin t$ at $r = 0.1$. Energy Conservation is safe!

Comment: thanks for the explanation, but if it's granted that at the source the value is sin t (or more generally, f(t)), then what will be the formula (f(r,t)) at the distance r, to satisfy, that f(0,t)=sin t, ensuring it won't be infinite?

Comment: "if it's granted" means? Oh. You want to deliberately ensure that there is no divergence at $r=0$. If that's what you meant, yes that can be done, though it will be an artificial construct. Make use of the discontinuous function $g(r,t) = f(0,t)$ at $r=0$ and $= f(r,t)$ at $r \ne 0$. I repeat, it trivially satisfies your desired condition, though it is definitely artificial.

Comment: Actually, it won't matter in the real context, this whole point particle thing is a mathematical construct. There are no zero radius things in reality, though sometimes there are good approximations. But with this inverse square dependence etc. one is generally concerned with the behavior at large $r$, i.e. how it falls off. The same divergence would technically also occur in the Newtonian gravitational force law, but we can live with it - one doesn't really need $r=0$ there, we can still predict eclipses and time period of orbit with a good accuracy, without bothering about the $r=0$ behavior

Comment: @AmateurPhysics - So, this artificial formula should work for practical purposes. :)

Comment: so, in real life, we can consider the wave source large enough to eliminate r<1 cases

Comment: I won't put absolute bounds, but your source will certainly extend beyond $r=0$. I meant, at least the troubles with that formula blowing up won't matter in a physical situation. But if you consider any two points outside the source radius, say $r$ and $r + \epsilon$, amplitude at the latter would be smaller, though even marginally. So, we can't really say in absolute terms that $r<1$ region is excluded.

Comment: I think I have the solution. Let's assume a source point (a sphere with $ radius > 0 $). As the wave crosses the surface between the source and the medium, (here the $ f(r,t) $ function is discontinuous), the amplitude increases, but the other properties of the wave modifies, the whole energy will be the same, and yep, energy conservation is safe :)